# Deserialize cookie auth using JWT

Tags: c#, jwt

I received this kind of string from cookie and i want de serialized it and want LoggedInId. 
Help will be appreciated .    `%7B%22Identity%22%3A%22nFBaiV3RT09D8up2YUNdkQ%3D%3D%22%2C%22LoggedInId%22%3A16%2C%22AgencyId%22%3A0%2C%22Email%22%3A%22pratik%40universal-software.com%22%2C%22FirstName%22%3A%22Pratik%22%2C%22LastName%22%3A%22Patel%22%2C%22ImageUrl%22%3A%22%22%2C%22UserTypeId%22%3A16%7D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decode it by url decoder (e.g. HttpUtility ), and after that you can deserialize it to class by e.g Json.net:

```
var urlDecoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode("jwt string here");

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JWtObject>(urlDecoded);

public class JWtObject
{
    public string Identity { get; set; }
    public int LoggedInId { get; set; }
    public int AgencyId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
}
```